# Python - Selenium Ubuntu installation

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu

I've installed Selenium in Ubuntu following the step in the web page http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html but when I try to execute these commands it appears an error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 135, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Then I read about geckodriver and installed marionette according to this web page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver but the same error appears.

I downloaded geckodriver I saved it in Downloads, so I uncompressed it and renamed the file to wires. Then I ran in the terminal:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/Me/Downloads/wires
```

I don't know what I did wrong, and I really want to use firefox without having to downgrade it.

EDIT: Solved using chromedriver instead of geckodriver.

Comment: Does renaming "wire"s back to  "geckodriver" help?

Comment: @nick_gabpe I've already tried it but it doesn't

Comment: Do an `ls -la` inside the `/home/Me/Downloads/wires`. Also do `echo $PATH` then tell us whether you run your script as `root`

Comment: @GeorgeD `ls -la`: `-rwxrwxr-x  1 Me Me 4480957 oct 10 13:51 wires`  `echo $PATH`: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/Me/Downloads/wires`. I didn't run the script as `root`, but I tried to and the same error appears.